# populating a tree with the file revisions

Tags: java

`The requirement is that a tree has to be populated with revisions of a file.

I have  a command  that fetches all the revisions of a particular file from MKS(Versioning system).

using the following command in java

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C "+cmd);
```

i get all the versions of file.c. now i want to populate the data onto a Tree structure. how do i do that?

```
try { 
 List<String> lVersions = new ArrayList<String>();
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C "+cmd); 
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 String line = null; 
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
 { 
   lVersions .add(line); 
 }
 }catch (IOException e) 
 { e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
```

lVersions contain the following output. It shows the all the revisions of a particular file. I need to populate this information on to a Tree structure.

```
1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.2
1.3
```

I have created a Tree Class

public class Tree {

```
private List<Tree> children = new ArrayList<Tree>();
private String label;
private Tree parent;
private String root;

public Tree() {
    super();
    children = new ArrayList<Tree>();
    }

    public Tree(String label) {
    this();
    setData(label);
    }

    public void setRoot(String root){
    this.root= root;
}
public String getRoot(){
    return root;
}
public void addChild(Tree child) {

    child.setParent(this);
    children.add(child);
}

public void removeChild(Tree node) {
    children.remove(node);
    node.setParent(null);
}

public void setParent(Tree parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public Object[] getChildren() {
    return children.toArray();
}

public Object getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return this.label;
}
public void setData(String label) {
    this.label = label;
    }
```

}

I have to generate the following tree structure and also remember the parent of each node. I am not asking for the code but some pointers as to how to start and to proceed would be very helpful !!!!

```
    1.1
 1.2    1.1.1.1
 1.3    1.1.1.2
 1.4    1.1.1.3
        1.1.1.4
```

Comment: Too vague, we wouldn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Using which UI technology: Web, Swing, SWT, ...?

Comment: 1. Google to find out how to populate trees. 2. If you still need help at least provide some code - what does the collection look like that you get back from MKS... etc...

Comment: Is it even about UI technology? When I read it I thought about trees as data structures. Anyway, user1688404 should explain what exactly his problem is.

Comment: You might have more luck getting answers if you actually stated what the input **looked** like.

Comment: @DavidGrant: I have updated how the input looks like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read the output of the command. See the API of `ProcessBuilder` for getting the output of the process as `InputStream` (output of process == your input, right?)

Parse the output into tree nodes. Each node has a `parent` reference and a list `children` with child nodes.

Comment: i am getting the first part of your answer. I am not sure how to do the second part?? i'm relatively new to Java..

Comment: If you want help with the second part, give us an example how the output of the process looks like and which information you need to preserve.

Comment: thankyou so much for replying. i was checking if i can upload a picture in this. i suppose not. can u please check the following link http://www.mks.com/support/productinfo/docs/SIE83_UserGuide.pdf pg 38. you will find the revision tree. i want to create something similiar to that but my aim is not to display the tree but to do 'diffs' on consecutive pairs of revisions.

Comment: Create the output in a console, copy a *few* important lines into an editor, remove any sensitive information, paste that into your question and click on the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: <pre> try {  
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C si viewhistory --fields=revision --hostname=aa-mks8 --port=6000 --user=username --password=password --project=/cc/Software/appl/project.pj aaa.h");  
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                 new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
             String line = null;  
             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                 System.out.println(line);  
             }  
         } catch (IOException e) {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         } <code>

Comment: i have updated the code which i have written to the main post

Comment: Run the code, copy a *few* important lines of the **output** into an editor, remove any sensitive information, paste that into your question and click on the `{}` button to format it as code.